# Symfony won't override mailer factories setting for "dev" environment

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm a bit of a Symfony noob, but I'm stuck on something I'm sure should work. I am using the "dev" environment on localhost, and am trying to test an action where an email is sent out to the user. I have the delivery_strategy set to none for "dev" but Symfony still tries to use the settings for "all". Here is my factories.yml:

```
prod:
  logger:
    class:   sfNoLogger
    param:
      level:   err
      loggers: ~
```

test:
  storage:
    class: sfSessionTestStorage
    param:
      session_path: %SF_TEST_CACHE_DIR%/sessions

response:
    class: sfWebResponse
    param:
      send_http_headers: false

mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none

dev:
  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none

all:
  routing:
    class: sfPatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true

view_cache_manager:
    class: sfViewCacheManager
    param:
      cache_key_use_vary_headers: true
      cache_key_use_host_name:    true

mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
      delivery_strategy: realtime
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host:       localhost
          port:       25
          encryption: ~
          username:   ~
          password:   ~

The error I get:

```
Connection could not be established with host localhost [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

## 10060]

I've checked that there's only on factories.yml file (for the application "frontend" level).

Thanks!
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the class as well, this works for me:

```
dev:
  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none
      transport:
        class:  Swift_NullTransport
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to symfony cc (or better do it mannally - clear cache folder)
2. Delete all unnessesary configuration in your factories.yml (double mailer, etc)
3. Order you configuration (order matter)

Here is my configuration:

---

```
prod:

test:
  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none

dev:
  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none

all:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
      delivery_strategy: realtime
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host:       itb1
          port:       25
          encryption: ~
          username:   ~
          password:   ~
```

Hope this helps.